# Is the sum of rank one matrices positive semi definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $n$ vectors $x_i$ such that $x_i\in\Re^n,i=1,\dots,n$, the matrix:
$$
A=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^T,
$$
is positive semidefinite?

Are there any results in literature?

Comment: Yes, it is PSD and it will be positive definite if the column vectors $x_i$ form a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute directly: $v^TAv = \sum_{i=1}^n |v^Tx_i|^2\geqslant 0$ hence yes, since $v$ is arbitrary.